# How to display and import data from a feed url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Have do i display and extract data from a feed url? 
And I only of the interest to import/display those there have the catogory_id of 10

This is the feed url:

`http://www.euroads.dk/system/api.php?username=x&password=x&function=campaign_feed&eatrackid=13614&version=5`

The format on the feed is:

```
 campaignid;;advertid;;title;;startdate;;enddate;;amountleft;;price;;percent;;campaigntype;;targetage;;targetsex;;category;;category_id;;cpc;;advert_type;;advert_title;;bannerwidth;;bannerheight;;textlink_length;;textlink_text;;advert_url;;advert_image;;advert_code;;campaign_teaser;;reward/cashback;;SEM;;SEM restrictions
```

Here is a sample code of the feed:

```
campaignid;;advertid;;title;;startdate;;enddate;;amountleft;;price;;percent;;campaigntype;;
targetage;;targetsex;;category;;category_id;;cpc;;advert_type;;advert_title;;bannerwidth;;bannerheight;;textlink_length;;textlink_text;;advert_url;;advert_image;;advert_code;;campaign_teaser;;reward/cashback;;SEM;;SEM restrictions <br/> <br/> 2603;;377553;;MP3 afspiller;;2010-07-21;;2011-12-31;;-1;;67,00;;;;Lead kampagne;;Over 18;;Alle;;Elektronik;Musik, film & spil;;7,13;;0,97;;Banner;;;;930;;180;;0;;;;http://tracking.euroads.dk/system<br/> <br/> /tracking.php?sid=1&cpid=2603&adid=377553&acid=4123&eatrackid=13614;;http://banner.euroads.dk/banner/1/2603/banner_21153.gif;;;;http://banner.euroads.dk/banner/1/2603/teaserbanner_1617.gif;;Allowed;;
```

Comment: Those samples are not valid RSS/Atom feeds. Are they some other (unknown) type of feed that is not a news feed? RDF/RSS/Atom are all XML-based and can be easily parsed using Nokogiri.

Comment: It is a API feed to automatic import campaigns. (Unknown feed) And it is really large. There is a PHP example of have to extract data from the feed. I will ask them if I may share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data format looks like a variation on CSV, if `';;'` is used as a column separator. Based on that:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.parse(data, :col_sep => ';;') do |csv|
  # do something with each record
end
```

`data` will be the content you receive.

Inside the loop, `csv` will be an array containing each record's fields. The first time through the loop will be the headers and subsequent times through `csv` will be the data records.

Sometimes you'll see `';;;;'`, which means there's an empty field; For instance, `field;;;;field` which would convert to `['field',nil,'field']` in `csv`. You'll need to figure out what you want to do with nil records. I'd suggest you'll probably want to map those to empty strings (`''`).